# knn realtime update based on feedback

Tags: python, python-3.x, knn

This is a bit idea hovering over my head.
knn is a lazy eval algorithm, so the data in the backend must be stored with categories.

I wanted to build a visual feedback where if we modify a point, any new prediction is based on the updated data. Is it possible to modify that information stored in backend?

Is it possible for knn to reference data from an external database, or do we need to retrain the model from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to re-generate the model if there is an update in the training data since the calculation for kth neighbor will change.